# How to download data from this site using R?

Tags: r

I have asked this question in R forum, however could not get any answer. Therefore I am trying my luck here, hoping someone can give me valuable suggestion.

I am trying to get data from this site:
http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/agricultural/grain-and-oilseed/corn_quotes_globex.html

Therefore I have tried following:

```
library(RCurl) 
library(XML) 

aa <- getURL("http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/agricultural/grain-and-oilseed/corn_quotes_globex.html") 
readHTMLTable(aa)
```

I will really appreciate if someone give me some light of the same.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to the SO. What is the problem with your code?

Comment: I can not download the data from that site using my code.

Comment: I think you need to pay for the data.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking how to explicitly break the terms and conditions of a website.

Comment: Read [the terms](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/md-disclaimer.html).  Among other things, "You may not develop or create any product that uses, is based on, or is developed in connection with any of the material (including, without limitation, proprietary data and indices) available on [the CME] site."

Comment: @GSee OP might have been trying to do that just for their own sake without a plan to turn that something into a product thus not violating the aforementioned statement. I'd call it a fair use if it is meant for a personal use.

Comment: This is javascript. The table is created dynamically. You'll have to copy and paste.

Answer (score 3):

How about getting the data from yahoo instead?

```
library(quantmod)
symbols <- c("ZCZ13.CBT", "ZCH14.CBT", "ZCK14.CBT", "ZCN14.CBT", "ZCU14.CBT", 
             "ZCZ14.CBT", "ZCH15.CBT", "ZCN15.CBT", "ZCU15.CBT", "ZCZ15.CBT", 
             "ZCN16.CBT", "ZCZ16.CBT")
getQuote(symbols)
                   Trade Time   Last Change % Change   Open   High    Low Volume
ZCZ13.CBT 2013-09-17 06:08:00 454.00  -2.50   -0.55% 457.00 468.50 453.25 135002
ZCH14.CBT 2013-09-17 06:07:00 466.50  -2.50   -0.53% 469.75 480.50 465.75  25952
ZCK14.CBT 2013-09-17 06:08:00 474.75  -2.50   -0.52% 478.00 488.50 473.75   9065
ZCN14.CBT 2013-09-17 06:08:00 481.50  -2.25   -0.47% 484.50 495.00 480.25  10312
ZCU14.CBT 2013-09-17 06:08:00 485.50  -0.75   -0.15% 489.25 496.75 485.00   1420
ZCZ14.CBT 2013-09-17 06:08:00 492.75  -3.00   -0.61% 495.75 504.00 492.00   7846
ZCH15.CBT 2013-09-17 06:08:00 502.50  -2.75   -0.54% 505.00 509.25 502.00    112
ZCN15.CBT 2013-09-17 06:08:00 519.00   8.25   +1.62% 519.00 519.00 519.00     15
ZCU15.CBT 2013-09-17 06:08:00 507.00   5.50   +1.10% 507.00 507.00 507.00      5
ZCZ15.CBT 2013-09-17 06:08:00 500.00   0.75   +0.15% 503.00 508.75 499.00    157
ZCN16.CBT 2013-09-17 06:08:00 510.25  -2.50   -0.49% 510.25 510.25 510.25      2
ZCZ16.CBT 2013-09-17 06:08:00 501.75   2.75   +0.55% 505.00 505.00 501.75      7
```